# What directory to publish Asp.NET Core application on desktop to?

Tags: deployment, asp.net-core, publishing, conventions, web-publishing

I come from the desktop application world (WPF, WinForms), where the convention is to deploy your exe to `\Program Files[ (x86)]\CompanyName\AppName\` directory, and store all the data in `\Program Data\CompanyName\AppName\` directory.

What's the corresponding convention for deploying Asp.NET Core web services on a desktop (not a server) PC?  `Program Files` directory doesn't seem like a good idea, because it requires admin credentials for writing, a problem you hit the moment you try to publish the app.  On the other hand, while `Program Data` doesn't have the permission problem, it just doesn't feel right, given there is no corresponding `Program Files` location.

I've also seen `C:\intepub\wwwroot\web-service-name` used, when IIS was involved.  Is that the way to go?  I'm guessing it makes sense when running Asp.Net Core app in Kestrel behind IIS as reverse proxy, but what if I were to host my app inside a Windows Service instead?

Comment: There is a lot of enduser as well as enterprise apps deployed as windows services with embedded web applications (using Apache, tomcat..etc) Under `Program Files`, Ex: HPE server admin/config tools. So for Kestrel APP, I would depoly bin in `Program Files` and logs,DB,etc under `Program Data`. it will works without permission issues since `dotnet` binary has the needed perms.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Post your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of enduser as well as enterprise apps deployed as windows services with embedded web applications (using Apache, tomcat..etc) Under `Program Files`, Ex: HPE server admin/config tools.

So for Kestrel APP, I would deploy bin in `Program Files` and write logs,DB,etc under `Program Data`. it will works without permission issues since `dotnet` binary has the needed perms.